# Listview dynamically loaded images - First list items shows all images loaded in the listview and then clears out

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So I am dynamically loading images from a urls for each listview item.

**Problem:**

I seem to have a bug where on loading the listview, the first listview item's ImageView flashes through all the images for all listview items. After all of them load, then one by one the listview items show their images and the first one gets its proper image.

I am not sure what is going on and why is this happening.

Here is my image loading AsyncTask.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView image) {
        bmImage = new WeakReference(image);
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap ) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap  = null;
        }

        if (bmImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)bmImage.get();

            // if the imageView was not retrieved
            if (imageView != null) {

                // if the image source is not empty
                if(bitmap != null){
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }else{
                    // set placeholder image
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.social_eyes_bare_owl));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: store Bitmap image to one property of your list and in `getView` method read from that instead of passing `ImageView`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, could you elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: Hi Georgi, did u ever resolve this? Having a very similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a similar image downloader. The problem might not be in the downloader but at the place where you are feeding the URL from. So if possible could you update the code where you are calling this image loader.